# How should i replace double space(continuous space) by double characters?

Tags: java, android, string

Please help me i have tried so many things i am not getting what i am looking for. yes it seems to be the easiest question on this planet to you but its not that easy that what i think.

here is it what i am trying to do

```
my_text="i have  a car";
String text=my_text.replace(" ","_");
```

i want value of text to be

```
text=i_have__a_car
```

but its value is

```
text=i_have_a_car
```

how should i replace that double space by double underscore?

Comment: I just checked your code and it works - http://ideone.com/TRlBDU. Are you sure you are not doing anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to double space, and double __

```
String text=my_text.replace("  ","__");
```

At the moment you are matching single space, and replacing with single underline.
If you put in double space, you will only match double spaces.

*edit, sorry at first i thought you were just trying to match double.

You can Then match single spaces after.

Though logically, it should still work as you suggested. So im not sure what you have done.

Are you definately sure there are not two `_` in the output, but it just looks like one?

altneratively, try character replace (Note that the single quotations replaces characters not strings)

```
String text=my_text.replace(' ','_');
```